# Backbone - Get model's idAttribute value from the collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am creating a generic table view that can be used with different collections. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
...
getModelIdAttribute: function () {
    return this.collection.__proto__.model.prototype.idAttribute;
},

getModelFromRow: function (HTMLrow) {
    return this.collection.get(this.dataTable.row(HTMLrow).data()[this.getModelIdAttribute()]);
},
...
```

The `data()` function returns an object with the attributes that were used to create the model, but I want to account for different idAttributes.

Currently, my way works - but `__proto__` is deprecated and it seems like there should be an easier way that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: The problem with that is that the object I have, for example `{ adminId: 2, name: "troy" }` is not a backbone model. I need to get that adminId value and use it to get the model from my collection, but I don't know which value I should use